# Shell script to remove and compress files from 2 paths

Tags: shell

Need to delete log files older than 60 days and compress it if files are greater than 30 days and lesser than 60 days. I have to remove and compress files from 2 paths as mentioned in PURGE_DIR_PATH.
Also have to take the output of find command and redirect it to log file. Basically need to create an entry in the log file whenever a file is deleted. How can i achieve this?
I have to also validate if the directory path is valid or not and put a message in log file if the directory is valid or not

I have written a shell script but doesn't cover all the scenarios. This is my first shell script and need some help. How do i keep just one variable log_retention and
use it to compress files as the condition would be  >30 days and  <60 days? how do I validate if directories is valid or not? is my IF condition checking that?
Please let me know.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_RETENTION=60
WEB_HOME="/web/local/artifacts"
ENG_DIR="$(dirname $0)"
PURGE_DIR_PATH="$(WEB_HOME)/backup/csvs $(WEB_HOME)/home/archives"

if[[ -d /PURGE_DIR_PATH]] then echo "/PURGE_DIR_PATH exists on your filesystem." fi

for dir_name in ${PURGE_DIR_PATH}
do
echo $PURGE_DIR_PATH

find ${dir_name} -type f -name "*.csv" -mtime +${LOG_RETENTION} -exec ls -l {} \;
find ${dir_name} -type f -name "*.csv" -mtime +${LOG_RETENTION} -exec rm {} \;

done
```

Comment: you can do simple arithmetic in bash ( `echo $((LOG_RETENTION/2))` ). If paths could have special characters (such as spaces) you can use arrays (`paths=("/a" "/b"); for f in "${paths[@]}"; do echo "$f"; done` - cf. `$*` vs `"$@"`)

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head -

```
#!/bin/bash
CSV_DELETE=60
CSV_COMPRESS=30
WEB_HOME="/web/local/artifacts"
PURGE_DIR_PATH=( "$(WEB_HOME)/backup/csvs" "$(WEB_HOME)/home/archives" ) # array, not single string

# eliminate the oldest
find "${PURGE_DIR_PATH[@]}" -type f -name "*.csv" -mtime +${CSV_DELETE} | 
  xargs -P 100 rm -f # run 100 in bg parallel
# compress the old-enough after the oldest are gone
find "${PURGE_DIR_PATH[@]}" -type f -name "*.csv" -mtime +${CSV_COMPRESS} | 
  xargs -P 100 gzip  # run 100 in bg parallel
```

Shouldn't need loops.